# How to represent many to many relationship

Tags: sql

I have an application and I have a many to many relationship that I can not wrap my mind around how to represent in a database.

I have users, users can create maps, and maps have elements, but when a user creates a map they can add other users to it to give them access to the map.

So...
One Map will have many elements
Elements will be tied to one map

One user will have many maps
Maps will have many users

Each map obviously has an ID column
Elements have a column for the Map they belong to

At first I imagined a map table that would have a column for user1ID and a column for user2 ID but now I want to allow as many users are they want.

How would this look in a database?

Comment: You could use a junction table! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity

Comment: Assume you want to have entries for table X with id as key and table Y alike. then you create another table XY with both X.id and Y.id as primary key.

Comment: thank you both! it's all making sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would create a `maps_users` table with columns `map_id` and `user_id`, and a primary key of `map_id` and `user_id`.
Bonus points if you add a foreign key from `map_id` to the maps `id` column in the `maps` table, and a foreign key from the `user_id` to the users `id` column in the `users` table.

Comment: So would the map table just be an ID? I wouldn't need a user column or anything like that now correct? I would just have a map table with a map ID. Then in the maps_users table I would have a map_id primary key column, which links to the map_id colum from the map table. And then users_maps would have another primary key user_id which links to the user_id field in the user table. I didn't realize you could have 2 primary keys in a table

Comment: Ah I got the tables created and primary keys from maps_users are set as foreign keys of the maps and users tables. I think that should be setup now. 

So when I create a map it will have an entry of the user who created it and the map id. Then when they add more users to that map there will be more entries into the maps_users table, one for each user_id and map_id. So then when I want to check if someone has access to a map I check for their id to be paired to the map id. Awesome. That all makes sense now, assuming my understanding is correct.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Information about maps in the `maps` table (id, title, who created it, creation date, etc...), information about users in the `users` table (user_id, name, email, etc...), and information about map users in the `map_users` table (map_uid, user_id, access_granted, timestamp, etc...)